# Why is 这件衣服有点儿深颜色 grammatically wrong?

Tags: sentence-structure

The correct sentence is 这件衣服颜色有点儿深.

I do not understand that why 颜色 is not put right after 深. Please explain to me.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Because it's the color that is a bit dark, and not "it's a bit dark color".

Answer (score 1):

有点儿深 is used to modified 这件衣服颜色, it is appropriate to put modifier after somethings you want to modified. For example 這個音樂非常好聽 you will not say  這個非常好聽音樂. So I use bracket parentheses to denote this structure as [Somethings] [description used to modified somethings]. There are tones of example you can find.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting fact: 珍妮 = precious girl = the name Jenny :):)

Depends on what you want to say, what you are talking about.

First, you are talking about the colour:

The colour of this garment is a bit (too) dark.
这件衣服（的）颜色有点儿深。

Now you are talking about a jacket:

I want to buy a dark-coloured jacket.
我想买一件深色的夹克。

Comment: In this case, why can 的 be omitted? I know in terms of meaning, 有点儿深颜色 is not correct.

Comment: 衣服颜色 = the garment's colour = the colour of the garment. Understand 衣服 as a possessive adjective: garment's, not as a noun. In Chinese, 的 is omitted at least as often as it is included! Think of: 我爸，我妈 as simple examples.